# Show/Hide function not working when implementing javascript in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

So, total newbie here when it comes to javascript and PHP but I'm steadily learning. Still, I'm gonna need to ask you guys for some help. I've tried to write a piece of javascript that shows and hides a div with text when a certain button is clicked.

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

When button A is clicked, it shows text A under it. When button B is clicked, it shows text B under it. When button C is clicked, it doesn't show anything.

I've worked everything out, but once I place it in the php file, the javascript function with the show/hide function doesn't work and the div's are kept on display: none when I click on the corresponding button.

I'm guessing it has to do something with how I'm placing the code in the PHP file, but I can't put my finger on what I'm doing wrong...

I hope someone here can help out! Thank you in advance for your help patience with a newb. :)

HTML:

```
<div class="option-50">
  50ml option selected
</div>

<div class="option-15">
  15ml option selected
</div>


<div id="50ml">50ml</div>
<div id="15ml">15ml</div>
<div id="set">set</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() { 
$('div').click(function(){    

  if(this.id == '50ml'){
    $('.option-50').show();
    $('.option-15').hide();

  } else if(this.id == '15ml'){
    $('.option-50').hide();
    $('.option-15').show();
  } else {
    $('.option-50').hide();
    $('.option-15').hide();
  }

})
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.option-50{
  background: red;
  display: none;
}

.option-15{
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the PHP code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used style property to assign `display: block` `display: none` to specific node for this purpose, please find below working code snippet and please make sure to import jQuery in your index.html:

```js
$(function() { 
        $('div').click(function(){    

          if(this.id == '50ml'){
            $('.option-50')[0].style.display = 'block'
            $('.option-15')[0].style.display = 'none';

          } else if(this.id == '15ml'){
            $('.option-50')[0].style.display = 'none';
            $('.option-15')[0].style.display = 'block';
          } else {
            $('.option-50')[0].style.display = 'none';
            $('.option-15')[0].style.display = 'none';
          }

        })
        });
```

```css
      div{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: cornflowerblue;
        line-height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;
      }

      .option-50{
        background: red;
        display: none;
      }

      .option-15{
        background: green;
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-50">
      50ml option selected
    </div>

    <div class="option-15">
      15ml option selected
    </div>


    <div id="50ml">50ml</div>
    <div id="15ml">15ml</div>
    <div id="set">set</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sarvesh,
That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help in this. If I may ask, since I'm still a beginner, what is the function of the [0] you used, and why didn't my code work instead? Hope you can help me out!

Comment: The main problem was that you are using jQuery, but you didn't imported it, and about '[0]', as I was using class selector that returns array of object having childrens as a nodes in DOM, and you want to access the first child

Comment: I see! How silly of me. Thank you again, also for you explaination about what I did wrong. This really helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the Javascript in script tags

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $('div').click(function(){    

            if(this.id == '50ml'){
                $('.option-50').show();
                $('.option-15').hide();

             } else if(this.id == '15ml'){
                 $('.option-50').hide();
                 $('.option-15').show();
             } else {
                 $('.option-50').hide();
                 $('.option-15').hide();
             }

        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi James,
Thanks for the reply! I already had the script tags, but forgot to include them in my code. Sorry about that, just edited them in. Thanks for the eagle eye :)